# Algorithm for finding the largest subgraph without a directed triangle

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

I would like to find the largest set of vertices in a directed graph. This set should not contain a cycle with exactly three vertices. Cycles with less vertices aren't possible with the given graphs; larger cycles can be in the set.

Do you know an algorithm for that?

Comment: @moose: So you're asking for an maximum induced subgraph without directed triangle, right?

Comment: If so, this is likely to be NP-hard, while I haven't found such a reference. Maybe it can be derived from some known NP-hard results of detecting induced subgraphs, since most of them are pretty hard.

Comment: It should be easy to reduce the 3-hitting set problem, hence NP-hard.

Comment: @Hsien-Chih Chang 張顯之: Exactly. Could you please suggest some knowen NP-hard results of detecting induced subgraphs? If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it if nobody else gives me a better answer until Wednesday.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title to "Finding the largest subgraph without a directed triangle" or something like that.

Comment: @arnab: I changed it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: NP-hardness follows by [Lewis and Yannakakis](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/hered.pdf)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem of finding a maximum set with no induced directed triangles is NP-complete via a reduction from maximum independent set.

Let G=(V,E) be an undirected graph and k be an integer, for which we wish to know whether there is an independent set of at least k vertices. Let |V|=n. From G construct a directed graph G'=(V',A'), where V' consists of the disjoint union of V and n additional vertices. For each undirected edge in G create two directed edges between the same vertices in G'. In addition, connect each of the n additional vertices in G' by edges in both directions to the vertices in V, but do not add edges between any two of the n additional vertices.

Then, a triangle-free set of vertices in G' consists either of a subset of V only (with at most n vertices) or it contains some vertices in the set of additional vertices together with an independent set of vertices in G. Therefore, there exists a triangle-free set of size n+k in G' iff there exists an independent set of size k in G.

However, this reduction produces many 2-cycles, so it leaves open the possibility that the problem might be easier in the case that the input graph has no 2-cycles, which you say is the case for your inputs. Unfortunately this special case is still hard: a more complicated reduction based on the same idea shows that the problem remains NP-complete even for 2-cycle-free graphs. In the more complicated reduction, add mn additional vertices rather than simply n. Replace each undirected edge in G by a directed edge, oriented arbitrarily. For each directed edge uv connecting two vertices of V, make n additional vertices in V', each of them connected to u and v to form a directed triangle. Then the resulting graph has mn+k vertices in a triangle-free set iff the original graph has k vertices in an independent set.

Comment: Thanks David for your detailed answer. It will take some time for me to understand your post completely. May I contact you if I have some more questions to this topic?